# Developer sessions from Dreamforce 2015

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

Anyone knows if the developer sessions have been recorded and where I could find these recordings? I'm looking for something like the videos on YouTube or similar from Dreamforce 2013.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As things get posted, the should be available from [Dreamforce on Salesforce Live](https://www.salesforce.com/video/#c0f-1c1c2c3c4). How quickly they'll appear (and which ones) is anyone's guess. With some, it's possible there might be technical problems that could prevent them from ever appearing. I'm told that's happened in the past. BTW, they do have videos on that channel from [DF14](https://www.salesforce.com/video/live/#/) as well.

Comment: Thanks for the links !

Comment: There is also a Repo ,so request all who delivered session to attach their ppt and videos in the public repo https://github.com/developerforce/df15-devzone-presentations

Comment: The DF14 link doesn't point to the sessions anymore. Is there anywhere I can find them ?

Comment: You should be able to find them on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?lclk=playlist&search_query=dreamforce+2014+sessions&filters=playlist) by searching using the key words "dreamforce 2014 sessions" then sort them by 'playlists'. A playlist with 109 videos came up at the top of the page for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwPgh7cjfLM&list=PLFSi-6JPTf9ghCYhGY8Q6pwK-iQcUcMhZ

Answer (score 1):

If you attended the event, go back to your agenda [here](https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q30000000DHQlEAO) - every session that was filmed should have a link to its video.  Not sure how to get so nitty-gritty if you didn't go (login-protected).

Comment: 2016 sessions at https://success.salesforce.com/MyAgenda?eventId=a1Q3000000qQOd9EAG - have a friend who went to Dreamforce inspect the page source for "vidyard_embed_code_" and get you the text that follows.  Then paste that after http://play.vidyard.com/ - that's the public link to the video.  (Same process for 2015, but with "agenda builder" link in answer above.)